# How is 'Tacenda' used in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am confused about the usage of this word. I know the meaning it conveys. Help?

Comment: OneLook finds the word in [only one dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=tacenda&ls=b&sourceid=Mozilla-search) where it means "Things not to be mentioned, things to be silent about"; I guess it's used in the same way as *Agenda,* "things to be discussed".

Comment: OED has much the same definition. I don't recall seeing the word before, but I assume if I ever did I might have guessed the meaning *in context* by extension from [***taciturn***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/taciturn). It's actually quite difficult to find an *English* usage in Google Books (I just see it turning up in hundreds of *Latin* texts). And given many/most people *won't* understand the term, I suggest that the answer to *"How is it used?"* should probably be ***inappropriately*** in most cases. Use ***taboo subjects*** instead.

Comment: @Fumble Or ***secrets***, which I suppose it might refer to as well. It is just the neuter plural of the gerundive of _taceō_ ‘be silent (about)’ in Latin, so ‘things that (one) should be silent (about)’. As opposed to _tacendi_ which, if you ask me, would be a brilliant term for small children.

Comment: @Janus: I'm sure the *tacendi* would be those silent sour-faced old women who look on disapprovingly wherever younger people are noisily having fun. I think those (mythical?) "small quiet children" (that we all wish ours could have been! :) are the legendary [***tacendini***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tacendini%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) - which if anybody *has* got one of, they obviously don't talk about for fear the Pied Piper will come along, introduce them to music / chatter, and lure them away!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, the sour-faced women would have to be _tacendae_ (or perhaps even the _tacentes_). I was playing with the transitivity of the Latin verb there: _tacendī_ could be either “those who must be silenced” or, _mutatis mutandis_, “those who need to STFU”. ;-)

Comment: @Shubham: I don't see how this question is likely to lead to a useful answer (useful either to you, or future visitors to ELU). You would gain more by taking this question to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) and asking someone there to explain how ***though*** is used in a sentence.

Comment: Usage: I go to the post office when I want tacenda letter :-)

Comment: This word deserves to be rehabilitated. 'Tacenda' dicenda est.

Answer (score 1):

[Tacenda](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tacenda) is an obsolete ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tacenda&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctacenda%3B%2Cc0)) term meaning:(from TFD)

> - tacenda, tacit - **Tacenda** are things not to be mentioned or made public—things better left unsaid; tacit means "unspoken, silent" or "implied, inferred."

- you are supposed to use more contemporary expressions (as suggested in a comment) such as  *taboo subject* or the common saying *elephant in the room*.

A few literary examples of sentences using *[tacenda](http://wordincontext.com/en/tacenda)*.

> - Most people who attempted such a task would sink into *being miserable blabbers of tacenda,* mere sieves through which matters of secret importance would granulate into the hands of ardent journalists. But at once to stimulate and gratify curiosity, and to give a quiet circle the sense of being admitted to the inmost penetralia of affairs, is a triumph of conversational art. 
>     (Arthur Christopher Benson - From a College Window)
> - That he was a fanatical moralist was something not even the broadest-minded among them suspected; they only knew that he meddled with a subject that was hitherto *considered tacenda, and with dire results*. Nowadays the thesis of Spring's Awakening is not so novel. 
>     (James Huneker - Ivory Apes and Peacocks)
> - Yet Zola lives despite these predictions, as the above figures show, notwithstanding his loquacity in regard to themes *that should be tacenda to every writer.* But in this matter of forbidden subjects Zola is regarded by the present generation as a trifle old-fashioned. When alive he was grouped with Aretino and the Marquis de Sade, or with Restif de la Bretonne.
>     (James Huneker - Ivory Apes and Peacocks)

Source: www.wordincontext.com

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's use the example: Miserable blabbers of tacenda. This means that they are talking about things that is better left unsaid. Think of someone/something that sometimes says something which no one wants to talk about, or is better left unsaid, like something inappropriate. Tacenda in a sentence could be: People on the internet sometimes write things I consider as tacenda.
There you go! I thought of someone that say things that aren't supposed to be said, or is better not to be said. Like that, I created a word in a sentence right away. Here are some other ones: My mother sometimes says things that my dad thinks is tacenda. Here's another one: When I'm called on, I sometimes end up blabbing random tacenda things like comments on the internet or other things.
Remember, it's great to include examples in your sentences. I hope I helped!

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please consider adding sources to support your answers.